# How can one define a conditional (per-environment) setting for Elastic Beanstalk environment with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

#### Desired outcome

I want to conditionally define a `setting` block for an `aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment` Terraform resource based on another variable, `environment`.

#### Current attempt

My normal go-to for this situation is to use `count`:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "backend_prod" {
  name                   = "backend-${var.env}"
  application            = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.backend.name
  solution_stack_name    = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.9 running Docker"
  wait_for_ready_timeout = "10m"

  # other settings omitted

  setting {
    count     = var.environment == "prod" ? 1 : 0
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
    name      = "API_KEY"
    value     = var.api_key
  }
}
```

#### Current outcome

Unfortunately, whenever I run `terraform plan` this results in:

```sh
An argument named "count" is not expected here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html):

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "backend_prod" {
  name                   = "backend-${var.env}"
  application            = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.backend.name
  solution_stack_name    = "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.9 running Docker"
  wait_for_ready_timeout = "10m"

  # other settings omitted

  dynamic "setting" {

    for_each     = var.environment == "prod" ? [1] : []
  
    content {
        namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        name      = "API_KEY"
        value     = var.api_key
    }
  }
}
```